# ISCSI vs ISCSId Services

Tags: iscsi, rhel7

From ISCSI clients, we execute `# systemctl start iscsi`. However, i can see there is another service called iscsi**d**.

Can anybody explain about **iscsi** service vs **iscsid** service in rhel7.?

Answer (score 3):

The iSCSI intiator (client) service are split to facilitate various use cases while making use of systemd socket activation so that long running services (iscsid) are only started if needed.

The iscsi.service is used to manage automatic login/logout of persistent records.  The iscsid.service manages the lifetime of iscsid, it will start automatically using socket activation when iscsiadm commands are run either from iscsi.service or manually.

So iscsid.service just runs iscsid, iscsi.service asks iscsid to connect to targets based on the configuration in /var/lib/iscsi

Answer (score 2):

`iscsi` is the client application. `iscsid` is the daemon application.

You use `iscsi` to connect to the `iscsid`.

**UPDATE**

`iscsid` is the service that runs on a server that holds the LVM(s) that will be shared to the clients.

`iscsi` is the client application that connects to `iscsid` server.

Comment: Are you saying `iscsid` service runs on a system of which act as a iscsi target.?

Comment: Yes.  See my update.

Comment: Ok, but there are more confusions. In my SCSI initiator (Client system) I see iscsid is running. Even when following up logs with `systemctl status iscsid` it show that it tries to access ISCSI target which runs on other system. So that mean it just not iscsi service access iscsid. However, in your reply says iscsi connects to iscsid.

Comment: This is incorrect. iscsiadm is the command that connects to iscsid. Please see the correct answer from @ChrisLeech below